# cordova run ios has stopped working

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

Suddenly (since yesterday - when I upgraded to OSX 10.12.5) I cannot run `cordova run ios` from the command line on either the simulator or a physical device.

Any help or hints would be appreciated - I am totally blocked.

I get

```
[ 65%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[ 70%] VerifyingApplication
[ 75%] CreatingContainer
[ 80%] InstallingApplication
[ 85%] PostflightingApplication
[ 90%] SandboxingApplication
[ 95%] GeneratingApplicationMap
[100%] Installed package /Users/rob//Junk/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/device/HelloCordova.app
------ Debug phase ------
Starting debug of b33a71e77db63cb8b28523eba033d1ece54c1ca1 (N42AP, iPhone 5 (Global/CDMA), iphoneos, armv7s) a.k.a. 'Rob’s iPhone' connected through USB...
2017-06-07 12:29:23.706 ios-deploy[7470:113619] [ !! ] Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory. This probably means you don't have Xcode installed, you will need to launch the app manually and logging output will not be shown!
Error: Error code 253 for command: ios-deploy with args: --justlaunch,--no-wifi,-d,-b,/Users/rob/Junk/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/device/HelloCordova.app
```

I have a `DeviceSupport` directory...

```
ls -l ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 rob  staff  170  1 Jun 12:13 10.3.1 (14E304)
drwxr-xr-x  5 rob  staff  170  7 Jun 11:54 10.3.2 (14F89)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 31 Jan  2013 5.1.1 (9B206)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 22 Jan  2013 6.0.1 (10A525)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 30 Jan  2013 6.0.2 (10A551)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136  6 Feb  2013 6.1 (10B142)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136  7 Mar  2013 6.1 (10B143)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 22 Apr  2013 6.1.1 (10B145)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136  9 Aug  2013 6.1.2 (10B146)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 14 Aug  2013 6.1.3 (10B329)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 10 Sep  2013 6.1.4 (10B350)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 12 Dec  2013 7.0.2 (11A501)
drwxr-xr-x  4 rob  staff  136 14 Jan  2015 7.0.4 (11B554a)
```

I have tried to create a completely new project with

```
$ cordova create MyApp
$ cd MyApp
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova run ios
```

Thanks

Rob

Comment: try updating your xcode

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode I did downgrade and now it works again!

Comment: Thanks Alex I'll give that a try.

Comment: I just downgraded to 8.3.2 and I still get the --- Signing Identity:     "-" --- error. @alex-kerber which version did you downgrade to?

Comment: I stoped working for me too. I run from Xcode now. Build works but not cordova run ios :/